# How to add an index with WHERE-clause in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing, where-clause

I would like to add an index with a `WHERE` clause in Postgres. I used the following query to do that:

```
create index concurrently em_openorder_idx on line (m_product_id, org_id, date) where date >= now() - 90
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
functions in index predicate must be marked IMMUTABLE
```

Comment: You cannot index the most recent 90 days -- that is what the error means.  Just index all the data.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? Looks like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: line is a big table so I wanted to create index with daterange. When we are creating index, it will have virtual table with only 90 days records. So Querying ll be faster @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: error exception is raised because now() is not an immutable function, its by all means volatile. you cant use volatile function  in any index.

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy: It's stable; unlike `clock_timestamp()`, `now()` never changes within a transaction. Doesn't make much difference here, though :)

Comment: Instead of trying to spoof partitioning, just go ahead and partition. Rename line to line_archive. Create a new line table with same structure and make it the parent of line_archive. Create a line_current table that inherits from line. Create a nightly process that moves data > 90 days old from line_current to line_archive. All new inserts need to go into line_current, but you can hide that from code with a before trigger on the line table. Updates and deletes will continue to work. You will still need the date index on both tables, but queries will be fast.

Answer (score 6):

The expression in the `WHERE` clause must be [immutable](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-volatility.html), i.e. for a given set of arguments, it must return the same value every time you call it. `now()` clearly doesn't qualify.

You can index the last 90 days worth of data like this:

```
create index concurrently em_openorder_idx on line (m_product_id,org_id,date) 
where date>='now'::date-90
```

However, if you go back and look at the index definition, you will see that it has been transformed into a constant expression:

```
... WHERE date >= ('2016-03-02'::date - 90);
```

In other words, this 90-day window will not automatically move forwards over time; you will need to periodically drop and recreate this index yourself.

Another thing to note is that your queries can only use this index if they are comparing `date` with an immutable expression. For example, the index will be used here:

```
SELECT * FROM line WHERE date = '2016-03-02';
```

...but cannot be used here:

```
SELECT * FROM line WHERE date = CURRENT_DATE;
```

---

As an aside, if you're on Postgres 9.5, this table might be a good candidate for a [BRIN index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/brin-intro.html).

Comment: I do object to the last statement, current_date will use index in that particular query

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy: It won't; see this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/185f1/2)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. True, if you use partial index, query with non immutable functions in where clause wont use index. But if you will index whole column, planner will use that index.

Answer (score 1):

Just create the index

```
create index concurrently em_openorder_idx on line (m_product_id,org_id,date)
```

I gues you want realize a query similar to this

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM line
WHERE m_product_id = @id
  AND date>=now()-90
```

This will use the index and should be very fast.

Comment: Here , it will do select from complete table which I am not expecting as table is huge

Comment: Nope, The index will filter the rows from you. If you add `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` as I just edit, you can see on the query plan how the index filter the data.

Comment: is date field a timestamp or date field? in where clause you could use current_date function instead of now()